# my alignment broke when adding padding in my div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a problem with my div alignment after adding the padding style into my code to make some space between my items. I'm sure the problem is coming from the padding because without the alignment, it is correct.
Anyone has any idea why the alignment is broken after adding the padding?
Thank you in advance for your help

```
  menuItem.innerHTML += `
                                    <div class="menus" style="padding: 20px">
                                    <div class="menu-item-name">${s.name}</div>
                                    <div class="menu-item-price">${ s.price}€ </div>
                                     <input type="submit" name="${nameValues}" value="Details" class="btn btn-default" onclick="passValue(name)"/>
                                     <a id="resa" href="${s.bookingLink}" class="btn btn-default">Reservation</a>
                                     </div>
`
                })
                map.set(key, menuItem);
```

This is the alignement which is correct without:
`style=padding:20px`
[image]

This is the alignmment after adding `style=padding:20px`
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CSS has something called a [box model](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_boxmodel.asp), which is just a fancy term for the way CSS calculates properties (like padding, borders etc).

In your case, I'm guessing that you're setting the width of these containers to a percentage value or similar (eg: width: 50%). On a 1920x1080 monitor, this renders this container to 960 pixels. The default behavior of CSS does not subtract borders or paddings from this, so if you add 50 pixels of padding, your container is now 1060 pixels (50px left, 50px right).

Since one container is now 1060 pixels and one is 960, you'd come out with a total of 2020 pixels, which is why they are not positioned side by side anymore.

To change the default behavior, you can use the box-sizing property.

```
.container {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Another approach could be to use [fractions / css grid](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/).